# Solr defining custom sort order

Tags: sorting, solr

I'm using Solr for offering faceted navigation to my site. However I need to define the custom sort order of facets and for the results.

Here is an example what I need to do.

Current Facets

Activities

```
Jogging (32)
Skipping (8)
Hiking (6)
Swimming (6)
Skiing (5)
etc
```

Requirement 1:
What I need to do is, define the custom sort order in the query, so that when user lands on the search results page then it will show all the results, but the results with Jogging tag will always load first, then skipping and so on.

Requirement 2:
If I am able to achieve 1, then there is more to it, from 2nd facet onward, I only need to load 5 results and the rest should get appended towards the tail of result set. For e.g. - Skipping will load just top 5 skipping and rest 3 will be added to towards the tail of entire result set.

Requirement 2 is good to have and I can push back on that requirement if its not achievable purely through solr query, but requirement 1 is a must.

I am pretty new to Solr right now and need to know the best way to handle it. Any help or direction will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
- RT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you looked at [boosting](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser)? For the second requirement, have you looked at: [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) ?